# How to add watermark in some pages?

Tags: graphics, backgrounds, watermark

I want to add picture in my text as a background. I do not want to add it to cover and table of content page. In the other hands, I want to transparent it to make a harmony beyond the text. Here are packages which I use to compile the text.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[top=35mm, bottom=25mm, left=20mm, right=30mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[noenc]{tipa}
\usepackage{tipx}
\usepackage[geometry,weather,misc,clock]{ifsym}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xtab}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}


\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{blue}}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}

\hypersetup{pdftex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, pdftitle=Feasibility Analysis Of Running The Initiative On Global Market In Iran, pdfauthor=Amin Karimi, pdfsubject=Feasibility Analysis Of Running The Initiative On Global Market In Iran, pdfkeywords=}
% Headings and outline numbering
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{0.1665in}{0.0835in}{\normalfont\normalsize\normalcolor\fontsize{18.2pt}{21.84pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\csname @textstyle#1\endcsname{\csname the#1\endcsname}\csname @distance#1\endcsname}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\newcommand\@distancesection{}
\newcommand\@textstylesection[1]{#1}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr}
\makeatother
\raggedbottom
% Paragraph styles
\renewcommand\familydefault{\rmdefault}
% List styles
\newcommand\writerlistleftskip{}
\newcommand\writerlistparindent{}
\newcommand\writerlistlabel{}
\newcommand\writerlistremovelabel{\aftergroup\let\aftergroup\writerlistparindent\aftergroup\relax\aftergroup\let\aftergroup\writerlistlabel\aftergroup\relax}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1mm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[bluelace,screen,nopanel,sectionbreak]{pdfscreen}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{-1cm}
\hspace*{3.5cm}

\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{pic/Logotext.png}
\end{center}


\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your code so that it includes the stuff needed to reproduce the problem i.e. it should be a complete document but not the stuff not needed i.e. all the irrelevant stuff in the bloated preamble you're using. (You should also edit that preamble for your own use: you are loading things multiple times, loading conflicting things or things which overwrite earlier things, and loading things in the wrong order. And that is really not a sane way to set up the page layout for slides. Also, `\makeatother\makeatletter` is simply pointless.

Comment: Would you please tell me which things are pointless? For example, when I delete `\makeatother\makeatletter` the text does not compile.

Comment: When you say `\makeatletter` directly after `\makeatother`, that's pointless. First you set `@` to be a letter. Then you set `@` to be other. Whichever it was to begin with, it ends up the same when you're done.

Comment: Why are you using A4 paper and a double-sided layout if you're making a presentation?

Comment: It is a report paper. I think it is a good template to write a report.

Comment: Then why are you loading `pdfscreen` and setting such loopy margins? However, the word 'template' says it all: you found a poorly designed 'template' and started from there rather than starting from a basic class and adding things you need for reasons you understand. This is not a good template (really, there are none, but even if there were) for writing anything. Start with `article`, `report` or Memoir's report class. (Or KOMA, if you can read German.)

Comment: To put this another way: I would not think about adding bells and whistles until you have a clean preamble. It will just further entangle the knot of code you have now. I realise that 'template's must be very tempting, but they only seem a short-cut. They will cost you dear in time, effort and hair.

Comment: So help me to do it better. tell me what is wrong with that? and How can I change it to tempting template?

Comment: Go through your preamble and remove duplicates. Then go through and comment out anything you don't know for sure you need. If everything still works, you can remove it. Definitely remove `pdfscreen` and change the margins. If you want serif for the body, remove the redefinitions of the default family. If you want sans (not recommended), make sure you have only the one change to the default family for that. Check your file encoding: is `latin1` correct?

Comment: Check the order of package loading e.g. `hyperref` should be last or nearly last. (Last unless a package specifically needs to be loaded after.)